# Colorbox Plugin - Disable iframe close, on outside modal window click

Tags: jquery-plugins, colorbox

While clicking outside modal window(iframe), it gets closed that's not suitable for forms etc.. how to disable this thing?? :S

Comment: and thatz the answer:
$("#cboxOverlay").unbind('click'); 

:D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please take a look at the website: http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

There's a table with al sorts of key/value options you can add to your colorbox method. 
One of the keys is: **overlayClose**
By default this is set to *true* and the description states:

> If true, enables closing ColorBox by
>   clicking on the background overlay.

Just add the key/value pair to the method call and you will have a modal window.

```
$.colorbox({ overlayClose: false });
```

This as an alternative to your answer/comment.

Answer (score 1):

escKey: false in the colorbox constructor should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#selector").colorbox({
    //your other colorbox options
    //...
    escKey: false,
    overlayClose: false
);
```

Hope this helps..